# Sorting Pandas dataframe hours by date

Tags: python, pandas

I made a dataframe by importing a CSV file. And I converted the date column to datetime and separated hours. And I replaced the hours 24 to 0 to be placed in the first row.

replace 24 to 0:

```
df['Hour'] = df['Hour'].replace([24], 0)
df
```

Here's the result:

```
           Hour  Value
Date        
2016-01-01  1   -1.09
2016-01-01  2   -2.41
2016-01-01  12  0.00
2016-01-01  13  0.00
2016-01-01  14  0.00
2016-01-01  0   0.00
... ... ...
2020-12-31  20  19.69
2020-12-31  21  20.78
2020-12-31  22  27.85
2020-12-31  23  19.68
2020-12-31  0   27.37
```

Also, I've been trying to sort the hour column by date. However, when sorting the hour it doesn't produce the result I wanted. What should I code to get the table below example:

For example (this is a desire table),

```
           Hour  Value
Date        
2016-01-01  0   0.00
2016-01-01  1   -1.09
2016-01-01  2   -2.41
2016-01-01  12  0.00
2016-01-01  13  0.00
2016-01-01  14  0.00
2017-01-01  0   0.00
2017-01-01  1   -5.03
2017-01-01  2   -2.75
2017-01-01  3  4.32
2017-01-01  4  0.00
2017-01-01  5  1.45
... ... ...
2020-12-31  0   27.37
2020-12-31  20  19.69
2020-12-31  21  20.78
2020-12-31  22  27.85
2020-12-31  23  19.68
```

I know this could be annoying you guys but, I would really appreciate your help...

Comment: Please provide a minimum, reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example - that will help us figure out exactly what you are getting and how to fix it. For instance, you say your are trying to sort the hour column by date, but didn't show us how you were trying to do that.

Comment: You are totally right Johnson, I'm newbie here haha... next time I'll make sure to provide a reproducible example. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `df.sort_values()`

```
df.sort_values(['Date', 'Hour'], ascending=[True, True])
```